# Analytic hypersurface as union of irreducibles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold. Then any analytic subvariety $V$ of codimension 1 (that is, any analytic hypersurface) can be expressed uniquely as the union of irreducible analytic hypersurfaces $V=V_1 \cup V_2\cup \cdots\cup V_m.$ Do we know if $m$ is always finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complex manifold $X=\mathbb C$ has $V=\mathbb N\subset \mathbb C$ as an analytic subvariety of codimension $1$, and the decomposition of that variety into irreducible analytic hypersurfaces has infinitely many  components, which are the singleton sets $V_i=\{i\}$: $$\mathbb N=\bigcup _{i=0}^{\infty}\{i\}$$

**Remark**
I'm sure it boosts the ego of a natural number to be called an analytic hypersurface: doesn't happen so often I guess...

Answer (score 1):

No, in general the union is only *locally finite*. If $X$ is compact, then the union is finite. You will find happiness in well-known Demailly's notes here : https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf at section 4.1. This essentially because the ring $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{C}^n,0}$ of germs is a noetherian ufd.

Comment: thank you, Demailly's notes are amazing.

Comment: You're welcome. I thought that giving to you a trivial answer was a worse answer than pointing you to Demailly notes. ;-)